# Show loading highstock

Tags: highcharts

I try to show a loading effect ([chart.showLoading()](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Chart.showLoading%28%29))  when my zoom is finished.

I used the events : "afterSetExtremes", "setExtremes", "redraw", but they don't work.

Example :

```
{
   events : {
       redraw : function(){
                   chart.showLoading('Loading...');
                }
   }
}
```

And I don't know where I put my chart.hideLoading() function.

I want the same effect : [lazy-loading](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading) but without async request.

Am I forced to use an async request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In setExtremes use `chart.showLoading('Loading...');` and in afterSetExtremes use `chart.hideLoading();`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was so easy. I'm ashamed !